# Is it possible to set a user's GitHub default organization?

Tags: github, github-enterprise

I belong to multiple organizations in Github (actually, it's a github enterprise installation).  Whenever I visit Github, the default organization is my personal user account.

[image]

However, all the repos that I work with are in another organization.  Is it possible to set the default organization when I visit Github?

Comment: I really want to know this!

Comment: Not possible. You currently have to log in to your personal account first and cannot access organizations directly. https://help.github.com/articles/how-do-i-access-my-organization-account